# Aggregate (count) rows that match a condition, group by unique values

Tags: r

It seems like such a simple problem, yet i've been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work:

Given this data frame identifying the interactions `id`had with `contact` who is grouped by `contactGrp`,

```
head(data)
   id               sesTs  contact    contactGrp   relpos   maxpos
1 6849 2012-06-25 15:58:34   peter        west    0.000000      3
2 6849 2012-06-25 18:24:49   sarah        south   0.500000      3
3 6849 2012-06-27 00:13:30   sarah        south   1.000000      3
4 1235 2012-06-29 17:49:35   peter        west    0.000000      2
5 1235 2012-06-29 23:56:35   peter        west    1.000000      2
6 5893 2012-06-30 22:21:33   carl         east    0.000000      1
```

how many contacts where there for `unique(data$contactGrp)` with `relpos=1` and `maxpos>1` ?

An expected Result would be:

```
1 west   1
2 south  1
3 east   0
```

A small subset of lines i have tried:

- `aggregate(data, by=list('contactGrp'), FUN=count)` yields an error, no filtering
- using `data.table` seems to require a key, which is not unique in this data…
- `ddply(data,"contactGrp",summarise,count=???)` not sure which function to use to fill the `count` column
- `ddply(subset(data,maxpos>1 & relpos==0), c('contactGrp'), function(df)count(df$relpos))` works but gives me an extra column `x` and it feels like i've overcomplicated it…

SQL would be easy: `Select contactGrp, count(*) as cnt from data where … Group by contactGrp` but im trying to learn `R`

Comment: I think you meant `west 2, east 0, south 0` for your expected results.

Comment: actually relpos=1. But yes for relpos=0 the expected Result is listed wrong…

Comment: Gah! You're right, sorry. It's early in the morning where I am. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this is the `ddply` version you're looking for:

```
ddply(sessions,.(contactGrp),
      summarise,
      count = length(contact[relpos == 0 & maxpos > 1]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Some of that syntax seems a bit obscure to me: the .( ) column notation, being able to refer to _columnName_[condition] as a parameter to the length function. I suppose i have some reading to do…

Comment: @LukasGrebe Sorry, the `.()` notation is a habit of mine, but isn't strictly necessary. You can also specify the grouping variables with something like `c("contactGrp")`.

Comment: Where did "sessions" come from and why are others using the word sessions in their answers? Has the question been edited since original post?

Comment: I think what joran meant was to include data-frame "data"? Can someone please validate? Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

And here is the `data.table` solution:

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(sessions)
> dt[, length(contact[relpos == 0 & maxpos > 1]), by = contactGrp]
     contactGrp V1
[1,]       west  2
[2,]      south  0
[3,]       east  0

> dt[, length(contact[relpos == 1 & maxpos > 1]), by = contactGrp]
     contactGrp V1
[1,]       west  1
[2,]      south  1
[3,]       east  0
```

Answer (score 11):

Your first attempted line with aggregate doesn't work because there is no function `count`.  You meant `length`.  All you had to do was execute that with conditional data selection for relpos and maxpos, and also select a dummy variable to get the count of (doesn't matter which).  Nevertheless, instead of using flexible aggregating commands of various kinds the built in `table` command is designed just for this.

```
with( data[data$relpos == 1 & data$maxpos > 1,], table(contactGrp) )
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an other approach:

```
a <- data.frame(id=1:10, contact=sample(c("peter", "sahrah"), 10, T), contactGrp=sample(c("west", "east"), 10, T), relpos=sample(0:1, 10, T), maxpos=runif(10, 0,10))

library(sqldf)
sqldf("Select contactGrp, count(*) as cnt from a where relpos=0 and maxpos > 1 Group by contactGrp")
  contactGrp cnt
1       east   3
2       west   1
```