# if statement with ddply function

Tags: r, if-statement, plyr

I am trying to use the if statement with ddply but am having issues with the if statement.

An example dataset is:

```
data<-data.frame(Gear=c(rep("S",10),rep("C",10)),TowSurvey=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0),TowCom=c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0),
    StationID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),Totwght=c(2,8,6,4,12,9,56,7,89,10),Totexpwght=c(5,8,12,45,89,56,23,78,56,41),
    Expnum=c(1,5,6,98,45,2,6,3,7,45),Exp=c(56,25,85,74,1,23,56,45,89,75))
```

My first try was

```
if(data$Gear=="S" & data$TowSurvey== 1 | data$Gear=="C" & data$TowCom== 1){
    datad<-ddply(data, .(StationID,Gear), summarize,Totwghtpertow=sum(Totwght),
    Totexppertow=sum(Totexpwght),Totnum =sum(Expnum),Totexpnum=sum(Exp))}
print(datad)
```

But the records that don't meet the if statement criteria are included in datad.

Then I found this post: Aggregate (count) rows that match a condition, group by unique values.  [Aggregate (count) rows that match a condition, group by unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580650/aggregate-count-rows-that-match-a-condition-group-by-unique-values/11580975#11580975)

So my second attempt based on the answer from the post was

```
datad<-ddply(data, .(StationID,Gear), summarize,Totwghtpertow=sum(Totwght[Gear=="S" & TowSurvey== 1 | Gear=="C" & TowCom== 1]))
```

I only tried with one column as a test and am getting the same results.  Any help would be appreciated in trying to figure this out.
Thanks

Comment: I think your answers are correct - the output is just including 0s where you filtered out all the values

Comment: So if it is correct, is there a way to remove records that do not meet the criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your first attempt you should actually get an error message since `if` can only evaluate a logical vector of length 1.

You really don't need an if statement here. Subsetting your data will do just fine.

```
data_sub <- subset(data, (data$Gear=="S" & data$TowSurvey== 1) | (data$Gear=="C" & data$TowCom== 1))
```

You can run your `ddply` statement using `data_sub` rather than `data`.

Or if you're going to be using the a lot you can wrap it in a function:

```
datad_func <- function(data){
data_sub <- subset(data, (data$Gear=="S" & data$TowSurvey== 1) | (data$Gear=="C" & data$TowCom== 1))
datad<-ddply(data_sub, .(StationID,Gear), summarize,Totwghtpertow=sum(Totwght),
             Totexppertow=sum(Totexpwght),Totnum =sum(Expnum),Totexpnum=sum(Exp))
rm('data_sub')
print(datad)
}

datad_func(data)

   StationID Gear Totwghtpertow Totexppertow Totnum Totexpnum
1          2    C             8            8      5        25
2          3    C             6           12      6        85
3          3    S             6           12      6        85
4          4    C             4           45     98        74
5          4    S             4           45     98        74
6          6    C             9           56      2        23
7          6    S             9           56      2        23
8          7    C            56           23      6        56
9          7    S            56           23      6        56
10         8    C             7           78      3        45
11         8    S             7           78      3        45
12         9    C            89           56      7        89
13         9    S            89           56      7        89
```

Comment: After taking a break and coming back to it I realized that subsetting the data and then using the ddply code would do the trick.  Than you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

`plyr` is not so good at subsetting in the function, so you can do it before or after like @scribbles said.

You could also try `dplyr` and pipe them together:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter((data$Gear == "S" & data$TowSurvey == 1) | (data$Gear == "C" & data$TowCom == 1)) %>%
         group_by(StationID, Gear) %>% 
         summarise_each(funs(sum), Totwght, Totexpwght, Expnum, Exp)
```